# Bootstrap "checkbox buttons" not working with forms

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Im using Laravel 5.2 with bootstrap. In the code you see that I use a "button" style for my checkboxes. This requires the `data-toggle="button"`. But now, no form submit buttons work anymore. Any ideas?

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="button">

{!! Form::open(array('url' => '/participants/add', 'class' => 'form-horizontal')) !!}

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="register" />

@foreach($data[$course->id]['freeParticipants'] as $participants)
<label class="btn btn-default addParticipants">
<input name="addParticipants[{!! $participant->id !!}]" type="checkbox" style="display: none;" autocomplete="off">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" aria-hidden="true"></span> {!! $participant->name !!}
</label>
@endforeach
{!! Form::close() !!}
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried using a button element instead of input for your submit button?